# Varying glyph spacing with fixed width glyphs

Tags: fonts, cairo, pango

I am trying to create a clock using a particular font (https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/play) where it is desired that the digits not move at all horizontally as time changes.  The font is not a fixed width font, but all the digits are identical widths.

The problem is that the date digits are not aligned as time changes (they are rendering with varying spaces as the digits change) when rendered by osgPango.    A fixed width font, Liberation Mono, does work as expected.

Looking at the font in Fontforge, the digit glyphs vary in physical width, but when the left and right bearing is added these are all identical width.  In other programs like Inkscape this renders as expected with a fixed width.

Is there some setting in osgPango or Pango that is overriding the font left and right bearings that can be disabled?  Or what am I missing?

Comment: So distilling your question to its core, are you asking for help in using osgPango? Because that's borderline off topic, and is usually met with "have you read the osgPango documentation to find this out yourself?" given the [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) policy on Stackoverflow. So... did you do your own research specific to osgPango first so you can tell us what you found (or didn't find)?

Comment: I do not believe this is specifically osgPango related. I'm wondering if there is some aspect of font rendering in Pango I am just not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix the issue by completely turning off hinting (CAIRO_HINT_STYLE_NONE).  This can be set on the osgPango context init method.